# IntelliJ problems view html problems

Tags: html, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to show the problems that occur in html files in the Problems or Project view? For example, I created an invalid html file that has a red line in it for an invalid tag. However, that error only shows up locally in the file, not in the Project view or Problems view.

I have setup a scope to include all files for the project, but html files don't seem to get captured.

Basically I'm looking for a way to determine at a high level which of my html files are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `Analyze` | **Inspect Code** with the appropriate profile to get results for all the files (or for the files from the specified directory/scope). In IDEA 12 it's moved to `Code` | **Inspect Code** menu.

Comment: That gets it to show up in the inspection view, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it have a red underline in the Project Files view like when a file has a compiler error

Comment: No, compiler errors in the project view are shown only from the `Build` | `Make` (like for .java files). As HTML is not compiling, errors are not shown in the Project View.

Comment: Guess that makes sense since they're not compiled. Thanks.